# trigonometric polynomial

Tags: trigonometric-polynomials

Can anyone tell me the following statement is true or not? Thank you.

There are two polynomials:
\begin{align}
p(r,\theta)
&=\sin(n_0\theta) + \sum_{j=1}^{\ell}a_j r^{n_j}\sin(n_j\theta),
\quad r>0\\
\widetilde{p}(r,\theta)
&=\sin(n_0\theta) 
+ \sum_{j=1}^{\ell}\widetilde{a}_j r^{\widetilde{n}_j}\sin(\widetilde{n}_j\theta),
\quad r>0
\end{align}
where 
$1\le n_0 < n_1 <\cdots<n_{\ell}$,
$1\le n_0 < \widetilde{n}_1 <\cdots<\widetilde{n}_{\ell}$.$\quad$
$n_j,\ \widetilde{n}_j\in\mathbb{N}$,

$a_{\ell}, \widetilde{a}_{\ell}>0$,
$a_j\geq0$, $\widetilde{a}_j\geq0$, $j=1,\cdots,\ell-1$.

If these two polynomials are different, then can there exists point $(r_0,\theta_0)$ such that
$$
p(r_0,\theta_0)\cdot \widetilde{p}(r_0,\theta_0)<0.
$$

The following is the original problem: 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {\sigma_k}
\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell}a_js^{n_j}}
{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell}a_js^{n_j}+\lambda_k}
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \widetilde{\sigma}_k
\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell}a_js^{\widetilde{n}_j}}
{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell}a_js^{\widetilde{n}_j}+\widetilde{\lambda}_k},\quad
\forall |s|<\epsilon.
$$
where 
$$a_j>0, 
n_j,\ \widetilde{n}_j\in\mathbb{N},
1\leq n_1<n_2<\cdots<n_{\ell},
1\leq \widetilde{n}_1<\cdots<\widetilde{n}_{\ell}.
$$

$$
\sigma_k,\ \widetilde{\sigma}_k>0, \mbox{and } \sigma_k\rightarrow\sigma_0(>0), 
\widetilde{\sigma}_k\rightarrow\widetilde{\sigma}_0(>0), \mbox{as } k\rightarrow\infty.
$$
$$
0<\lambda_1<\cdots<\lambda_k<\cdots\rightarrow\infty,
0<\widetilde{\lambda}_1<\cdots<\widetilde{\lambda}_k<\cdots\rightarrow\infty, 
\mbox{as } k\rightarrow\infty.
$$ 
Can we derive $\{n_j\}_{j=1}^{\ell}=\{\widetilde{n}_j\}_{j=1}^{\ell}$,
$\lambda_k=\widetilde{\lambda}_k$, $\sigma_k=\widetilde{\sigma}_k$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Where does this statement come from?

Comment: Maybe this old result of Fejer will help you get started: if $f(\theta)$ is a trigonometric polynomial with real coefficients such that $f(\theta)\geq 0$, $\forall \theta$,  then there exists a polynomial $p(z)$ such that $f(\theta)=|p\bigl(\; e^{\sqrt{-1}\; \theta}\;\bigr)|^2$, $\forall \theta$.

Comment: I added the original problem.